# I cant set the UINavigationBarTitleItem. How do I set it?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios-simulator, swift4

I am having a problem with my navigation title and setting it with code.

Here is the structure of my code:

```
Navigation Controller -> TableView -> UIScreen where i want to set the title.
```

Here is my code:

TableViewController:

```
     import UIKit

  class ProductsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

let cellId = "cellId"
let products = [

    "Happy Face",
    "Sad Face",
    "High Five",
    "Angry Face",
    "The Earth"
]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return products.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserCell

    let product = products[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = product

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let buyProductViewController = BuyProductViewController()
    let product = products[indexPath.row]
    buyProductViewController.nameOfItem = product

    buyProductViewController.navigationItem.title = product

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
}
 }

  class UserCell: UITableViewCell {

 }
```

Setting my title View Controller:

```
import UIKit
```

class BuyProductViewController: UIViewController {

```
var nameOfItem: String? {

    didSet {

        print(nameOfItem)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

}

I would very much appreciate if any1 could help me because I am very upset and have been working on this over a week and only just came across stack overflow.

Thanks.

Comment: try `self.title = "title name"` set into `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you if: 
 1. ProductsTableViewController is embedded in UINavigationController;
 2. Segue with identifier "segue" is push. Note the difference is directly setting the title of your pushed controller. NavigationBar automatically uses the displayed VC's title as navigation bar title.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let buyProductViewController = BuyProductViewController()
    let product = products[indexPath.row]
    buyProductViewController.nameOfItem = product

    buyProductViewController.title = product

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: so what is the fix?

Comment: Setting the `title` property of the ViewController and the iOS will handle the rest. `buyProductViewController.title = product` and not working with `.navigationItem` property. If this is not working either point 1 or 2 from above is not precondition.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have to set title in `BuyProductViewController`:

```
import UIKit
class BuyProductViewController: UIViewController {
    var nameOfItem: String? {
        didSet {
            print(nameOfItem)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = nameOfItem
    }
}
```